# React element does not render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, element

I have been trying to render a simple element using React. For some reason, very similar examples do work, but my code just can't get working. I can't see any errors, can you please advise me?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.6.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.6.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

    var ExampleElement = React.createClass({

        render : function() { return (<p>P</p>); };

    });

    React.render(<ExampleElement/>, document.getElementById('example'));

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `;` after

```
render : function() { return (<p>P</p>); };
                                          ^^
```

Also instead of `React.render` use `ReactDOM.render`

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/28091/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ReactDOM.render` and not `React.render`.

In React 0.14 the `render` function was moved from the `react` package to `react-dom` instead and you also have a stray semicolon after your render function which will cause issues for you since `React.createClass` takes an object.

Comment: I tried to do it as 'ReactDOM.render(<ExampleElement/>, document.getElementById('example'));', doesn't work, either.